# firestore query does not return documents inside flutter/dart mobile app, but works in javascript

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Very strange behaviour I am experiencing  with firestore.

Below dart code does not return the value

```
await Firestore.instance.collection('users')
          .where("phoneNumber", isEqualTo: phoneNumber)
          .getDocuments();
```

The javascript code from web returns the value

```
db.collection('users').where('phoneNumber', '==', 'xxxxxxxxxx').get().then((result) => {
       console.log(  result.docs.length )
}).catch((err) => {
console.log(err)
});
```

But I can clearly see the phone number does exist in the colection. 
I just don't know if this is because of pending writes or cache. Where can I disable it if that is the case?

edit the code for phNumber

```
Future<User> getPhoneUser(String phoneNumber) async {
    if (phoneNumber == 'xxxxxxxxxx') {
      print('yes the phone number is same');
    }
    try {
      QuerySnapshot qsnap = await usersRef
          .where("phoneNumber", isEqualTo: phoneNumber)
          .getDocuments();

      int length = qsnap.documents.length;

      if (length > 0) {
        DocumentSnapshot doc = qsnap.documents[0];
        doc.data['id'] = doc.documentID;
        doc.data['createdAt'] = doc.data['createdAt'].toDate().toString();
        doc.data['updatedAt'] = doc.data['updatedAt'].toDate().toString();
        User user = User.fromJson(doc.data);
        return user;
      } else {
        return null;
      }
    } catch (error) {
      return null;
    }
  }
```

Comment: are u sure phoneNumber is not null?

Comment: @PeterHaddad , yes the phonenumber is not null. There is not much code apart from this call.
````
var db = firebase.firestore();
var Timestamp = firebase.firestore.Timestamp;
````

Comment: Where are u assigning the phoneNumber

Comment: I edited with the code for phoneNumber. I am also getting the print statement in the console. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are running your flutter app on a simulator, sometimes the simulators go offline for some reason and you can no longer fetch data from the network.

If this happens, you can restart your simulator to bring the network connection back. I would suggest debugging with an actual physical device whenever possible.

Comment: Yes, it was on simulator, tried this option, but no luck :(

Comment: @p2hari I'm sorry to hear that. Have you tried it on a physical phone?